# Maximum and Maximum difference of integers in args variable

Tags: java, integer, max, minimum, args

I am writing a code that calculates the maximum number in my args variable as well as the largest difference between the highest and lowest integer in args.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
public int max(int [] args) {//array of ints
    int m = args[0]; // first element

    //initialisation; condition; update
    for (int j = 1; j < args.length; ++j) {
        // statement in a block:
    if (m < args[j]) {
        m = nums[j];
        // if m is less than the j-th element
        // then store this new smaller value
        }
    }
    return m;
```

}

```
    public int min(int [] args) {//array of integerss
        int mi = nums[0]; // first element

        //initialisation; condition; update
        for (int j = 1; j < args.length; ++j) {
            // statement in a block:
            if (mi > args[j]) {
                mi = args[j];
            // if m is greater than the j-th element
            // then store this new largest value
        }
    }
        return mi;
```

}
        //compute average by dividing sum of numbers over the count

```
    public void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);

        SimpleCalc fm = new SimpleCalc();
        **System.out.println(fm.max(nums));**
        **System.out.println(fm.max(nums) - fm.min(nums));**
```

It was returning values when i used arrays, but it doesnt seem to compile with args. Im not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because `args`, in the `main` method is an array of `String`s. Your methods take an array of `int`s as argument. You should thus transform the `args` array of `String`s into an array of `int`s, and pass this new array of `int`s to your `min` and `max` methods. Use `Integer.parseInt` to transform a `String` into an `int`

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have a typo in `max()`:

`m = nums[j]` should be `m = args[j]`.

also  in `min()`, `int mi = nums[0];` should probably be `int mi = args[0];`

also, where does `nums` [in main] comes from? you should create this array before passing it to `max()` and `min()`